# Efficient Multi-threading in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm currently in the introductory stages of writing multi-threaded programs in C. I understand how to create separate threads with completely separate functions but I'm wanting to understand how programmers in the field break down a single task to take advantage of multi-threading. I've gone through several exercises for synchronizing separate threads but nothing good when it comes to breaking down a single task and making it quicker with multiple threads. I'd really appreciate some wisdom when it comes to solving these types of problems and explain *how* and *why* you would attack a problem in that particular way.

As an example, lets say this is the task I'm trying to tackle with multiple threads. [It multiplies two matrices together creating the c matrix with n x p dimensions.] And lets also say we can input how many threads we want to run between 1 and t (even though there won't be a significant performance difference in threads >= 4) so it's obvious how to attack it.

```
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
     for (j = 0; j < p; j++){
         c[i][j] = 0;
         for (k = 0; k < m; k++){
             c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
         }
      }
  }
```

My first thoughts are to basically divide each loop up according to how many threads. So, for *t* threads,

```
 for (i = 0; i < n / t; i++){
     for (j = 0; j < p / t; j++){
         c[i][j] = 0;
         for (k = 0; k < m / t; k++){
             c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
         }
      }
  }
```

And then synchronizing them with semaphores. But this would have to separate each part of the problem into t-cohesive threads that don't overlap or miss any of the matrices. This seems a little much and I have a feeling there's a better way to attack it. How would you guys go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are m operations involving multiplying a row of the left matrix by a column of the right matrix. For t threads, each thread could perform m/t operations. If m is not a multiple of t, then decide how to split up the work. Using m/t means the last thread does more work, using (m+t-1)/t means the last thread does less work, or use (m/t)+1 operations on some threads and (m/t) operations on the remaining threads.

This is probably not a good case for multi-threading, but at least you get an idea of the concept.

Here's a link to an example of Windows based multi-threading used for a merge sort, using 4 threads for about a 3x increase in performance. I had previously thought that the key loops in the merge function were so small that the process would be memory bound, but it turned out to be cpu bound.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148025/multithreaded-bottom-up-merge-sort

Comment: Super helpful - after thinking on this for a while this is the route the I've been considering. I'm not familiar with how to see if it would be memory or cpu bounded - could you elaborate on that or point me to a good article? I'm still pretty new to this side of C and multi-threading.

Comment: @n_kritz - In the multi-threaded merge sort, the key loop is in merge, compare two integers, move the smaller integer to the output arrary, increment the indices, check for end of run, and loop back to the compare. That's a fairly small loop, but it's cpu bound and not memory bound for a single thread. If you look at that example again, the effective memory throughput (bandwidth) for the single versus multi-thread implementations is shown.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel computing (OpenCL and also vectorization) is the best way to do multiple tasks on the same object. Maybe one of the best usage examples of multithreading is a typical "Client-Server chat communication&I/O". An MT server is a lot more efficient than a multiprocess server because each operation of communication does not costs enough to be handled by a single process.

If I consider your matrix problem I would approach it by using GPU power and parallel computing with OpenCL because with it every single element in the matrix can be processed at the same time than the others.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/icaromagalhaes/7854709d740a247e81a1b2e5f154925c) is an example of matrix addition with OpenCL

If I must use threads I will break the problem by creating n threads (where n are the number of physical (or even logic) cores of your CPU and dividing the computation of the matrix in n parts just as you have done. Obviously, there's a mutual exclusion to be handled by semaphores. Please note that by using pointer arithmetic the matrix will be attacked contemporary by the threads.

EDIT: Please note that the multithread solution will work efficiently only if the CPU is multicore, in the case of a single core CPU, arithmetic multithread operations are more efficient than mono thread solution.

If this does not answer your question, please be more precise about what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenCL or vectorization at this point. Would it be worth diving into that prior to understanding how to breakdown the task at hand?

Comment: What do you mean that the matrix will be attacked contemporary by the threads if using pointer arithmetic? I apologize for the ignorance - I'm new to this side of C.

Comment: instead of declaring a static double array for a matrix, you can use dynamic memory assignments, so you can see a matrix like a pointer. By passing this point as arguments of every thread your matrix will be processed by more threads contemporary. [Here](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html) you can find info about pointers arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to split it into pieces and assign one to each thread. First, that's a lot of work. Second, that performs very poorly under all kinds of realistic conditions.

For example, suppose you have a machine with four physical cores and eight virtual cores and you create four threads and give each one quarter of the work. If one physical core is occupied when your code runs, two of your threads will share a physical core. When the two "fast" threads that have their own physical core finish, you'll have three physical cores but only two threads running. Yuck.

Why arrange things so you have to figure out the optimal division? It's extra work and it makes your code slow if you figure things out wrong. Don't do that.

Instead, divided the work into sensible chunks, and let each thread use the following algorithm:

1. Is there a chunk of work that has not been started?
2. If no, wait and go to step 1.
3. Do that chunk of work.
4. Go to step 1.

So you can divide your matrix work into a large number of convenient piece and create a pool with a sensible number of threads. Then the threads can run at whatever concurrency works best, and so long as there's enough work left to do, all cores will stay busy.

In other words, you are thinking about the problem the wrong way and trying to do the scheduler's work. Don't try to assign specific work to specific threads -- it's too hard to get it right.

Comment: In some cases, dynamic handling of chunks is not needed. Whether a core is "occupied" or not depends on the operating system. For example, Windows tends to redistribute processes and threads on each time slice to reasonably balance the load between cores, so simply splitting up the work into 4 chunks for 4 cores (or 8 if hyperthreading is going to help) is often good enough.

Comment: @rcgldr It may be good enough in some cases, but it's a lot of extra work just to hope that "good enough" is good enough. Why do extra work to make things worse?

Comment: @rcgldr But now you've solved the problem for the one case where you have precisely four cores of precisely equal speed. So you've put in as much effort as you'd need to solve it in the general case and you've only solved it in one case. And, worse, in realistic conditions, even if you think you're in that one special case, you typically won't quite be. (For example, one core may get the vast majority of the interrupts, leaving a significant amount of time when only one core is working.)

Comment: @rcgldr Either you can divide the job into suifficiently independent work units or you can't. If you can't, neither technique will work. If you can, either technique will work. So that's not a reason to prefer one method over the other.

Comment: Dividing it up the way @rcgldr mentioned seems a little more straight forward to me but I'd like to grasp what you're talking about as well. Is there any way you could apply that algorithm to the example I provided? It might be more digestible.

Comment: @n_kritz - For the matrix multiply, there are m "chunks", where each chunk multiplies one row by one column. My suggestion was to split up the work evenly between threads. David's suggestion is to have some way of indicating which of the m chunks need to be calculated in a common resource (such as a counter), then for each thread to "allocate" a chunk to be worked on from the common resource. The common resource interface would need to be multi-thread safe. In both cases, the main thread waits for the others to complete as an indicator that all chunks are completed.

Comment: @n_kritz - David's method is more flexible, but it involves something similar to single producer, multiple consumer issue, multiple threads synchronizing and updating some common resource, The synchronized common resource seems more complicated than splitting up the work before the threads get started, which would eliminate the synchronization issue for starting the calculations.

Comment: @rcgldr You wind up needing a synchronized common resource anyway. Otherwise, how can you wait for all the threads to finish doing their assigned work and know when your results are ready? Obviously, you wouldn't make the number of work units so large, or each work unit so small, that the dispatch overhead is more than negligible.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - For this example, with either method, the main thread can simply wait for the other threads to terminate, which doesn't require a common resource. I used thread termination to deal with the post completion synchronization in [multithreaded merge sort](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148025/multithreaded-bottom-up-merge-sort) .

Comment: @rcgldr It does require a common resource -- the table of threads that belong to the process. And it's an extremely inefficient one at that because thread creation and destruction requires OS involvement, passes into the scheduler, and so on.

Comment: @rcgldr If any of that affects you performance measurably, you're doing something horribly wrong. On the other hand, thread creation and destruction is very expensive.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - I deleted some of my prior comments. I don't get the point about the overhead of thread creation and deletion, this has to occur in order to create the threads and for the process to terminate. I don't consider a table of threads as a common resource, since that's internal to the OS. In my example, at the end, you have a thread waiting on multiple separate resources. I chose to use thread termination, but it could have been multiple semaphores, and with Windows, it could be an array of semaphore (or thread handles) using a single WaitForMultipleObjects().

Comment: @rcgldr Sure, you need to create the threads once and you need to terminate the threads for the process to terminate. But that doesn't mean you need to create threads each time you want to assign work to a thread. And that doesn't mean you need to terminate a thread each time you need to know that some work unit is done. Imagine using threads to do matrix multiplication and then having 100 multiplications to do. Do you want to create and terminate a set of threads 100 times or just once?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - I do a one time creation. I normally use one (or more) semaphore(s) per thread to start or to continue that thread. Other times I use a messaging system (each message queue uses a semaphore an mutex), which I would also use for a "single queue" multiple thread scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

For matrix operations especially small matrices, you will probable be best off using SIMD. Threads really come into theirvown for largish long running tasks. For short tasks, tge overhead becomes prohibitive.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SIMD.